# plot column name on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have 20 columns corresponding to 20 device names and only one row with values throughout the all columns. I want to plot machine names on x-axis and corresponding row value on y-axis

```
df

     device-1     device-2     device-3     device-4     device-5... 
0           1           5             0.5          4           2.5
```

I want to have dots on the graph for each device

anybody could please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:-

```
cols =list(df.columns.values)

for i in range(0,len(cols)):
    plt.scatter(i, df[cols[i]])
plt.xticks(list(range(0,len(cols))))
plt.axes().set_xticklabels(cols)
```

Comment: tha's great. Thanks a lot! What if I want to add to this plot, another plot,  y=1 linear equation. How would you do that please?

Comment: I wrote plt.axhline(y=1, color='r', linestyle='-')

plt.show()
but it shows the plot on a different graph

Comment: just add ```plt.plot( cols,[1]*len(cols))``` in the end.

Comment: looks better than what I did. Thanks

Comment: last question. I am doing curve= plt.plot( cols,[1]*len(cols)), and curve.ylim(0.5,5) but gives an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ylim'. I want to set min and max of y axis